# change positive number to 1 using bitwise operators

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, bit-manipulation

I am querying a `hive` table.

Sample data like this

```
userid  count  date_time
 1       123    2015
 1       12     2015
 2       12     2015
 2       0      2015
```

Expect result:

```
1  2  2015
2  1  2015
```

What I want:`If count> 0, the count is  1, otherwise count is 0`(PS:count is non-negative).

My query:

```
select uid, sum(count), date_time from count_table group by uid, date_time
             ^^
select uid, sum(count&1), date_time from count_table group by uid, date_time
```

I search about `bit-manipulation`, but could not find solution yet.

How to do some `bitwise operation` on `count`, to make positive number to 1 by updating my sql.

Any idea how to solve this, thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

I am using `HIVE`, so the operation is within `hive-sql`.

HIVE support `Arithmetic Operators`like `+ - * / % | & ~ ^`. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: its db operation and anyways he didnt supply Code snippet only sql query means he wants answer containing SQL only.

Comment: It's not bit manipulation, but maybe try sum(sign(count))

Answer (score 0):

You can change `sum(count)` with `IF(sum(count)>0,1,0)`

IF needs three parameters: the condition to check, expression returned if true and expression returned if false

Comment: This works. Is there a way to use `bitwise operation` on count?

Comment: What is the `count` representation? If it signed you can invert the sign bit, but I don't know if you can do it inside a SQL query

Comment: `count` is `BIGINT`(non-negative). I update my question.

Comment: Maybe what the OP wants is more like `sum(IF(count > 0, 1, 0))` - in other words the count of non-zero values, rather than whether the sum is non-zero?